# How to remove IP prefix from URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, ip

Trying to figure out how to remove the IP the is pre-fixed to my URL once I move off the homepage.

http://www.clpromotions.co.uk/

http://217.199.187.59/clpromotions.co.uk/index.php/about-us

Tried everything - perhaps it's something simple that I'm missing. The site has recently been migrated....

Comment: `<base href="http://217.199.187.59/clpromotions.co.uk/" />`

Answer (score 0):

Use reletive url path and add the `base` in head

```
<base href="http://www.clpromotions.co.uk/" /> 

<a href="clpromotions.co.uk/index.php/calendars">Promotional Calendars 2016</a>
```

Or make a `constant` base url and append on each link

```
Const BASE_URL = 'http://www.clpromotions.co.uk';

<a href="<?=BASE_URL?>/index.php/calendars">Promotional Calendars 2016</a>
```

Or you can start the url with domain root with `/`

```
<a href="/index.php/calendars">Promotional Calendars 2016</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much.

I found the issue in config under

```
$config['root_path'] =
```

Thanks.